# Android NDK - How to resolve K&R style function declarations

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

I need to compile some c source code, and there are a lot of K&R style function declarations in it like this:

```
static int
foo(bar) // no type info
char bar; // the type is declared here
{
    return bar * 2;
}
```

I'm using Android Studio and CMakeLists to build these files, it complains that "**Can't resolve type 'bar'**", so I guess it cannot recognize K&R style function declarations.

Is there any way to resolve this kind of problem?

**2018/05/10 Updated**

At last, I found out that although Android Studio shows "**Can't resolve type 'bar'**" in red error messages, I can still run the project on an Android device with correct behavior. (The calculation result of K&R style functions are all correct)

My environment:

- macOS 10.13.4
- Android Studio 3.1.1
- NDK 16.1.4479499
- CMake 3.6.4111459

Comment: Make sure that the code is compiled with `clang` and not `clang++`. That is, don't give the file a `.cpp` extension (or include such code in a source file that has a `.cpp` extension).

Comment: Thanks, I have confirmed that the files are in .c extension and they are not included in any .cpp files.

Comment: Ok, well, I haven't tested this with the version of clang that comes with the NDK. But with clang 3.7.0 on Windows (msys64) your function compiles just fine.